# Split 100 times randomly train and test data using caret in R

Tags: r

To better estimate the accuracy of the classifier, I would like to carry out classification procedure which will be repeated 100 times with randomly changing sets of training and test samples (divided 50% by class). I don't know how to split this sets randomly and repeat it 100 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create multiple splits based on the outcome variable at once with the `times` argument to `caret::createDataPartition()`.

For example, the following line of code will produce a list of 100 numeric vectors of data indices. (Note: I set `list = TRUE` so we can use `purrr::map()` next)

```
indices <- caret::createDataPartition(extracted$class, p = 0.5, list = TRUE, times = 100)
```

Now you can use `purrr::map()` to iterate over each and get a list of training and testing sets.

```
resample_data <- tibble(
  training_sets = map(indices, ~ extracted[.x, ]),
  testing_sets = map(indices, ~ extracted[-.x, ])
)
```